# Laravel: Why does function parameter change to empty array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a function that accepts some optional parameters used to filter some data for reports. For some reason, my optional dates changed into empty arrays when I added a third optional User parameter (implicit binding).  Why is that?

```
//Example URLS
example.com/reports // Breaks because $start_time & $end_time are now arrays for some reason
example.com/reports/2018-02-01/2018-02-01 // Works Fine
example.com/reports/2018-02-01/2018-02-01/neve12ende12 // Works Fine

//Route File
Route::get('reports/{start}/{end}/{user?}', 'ReportsController@index');
Route::get('reports','ReportsController@index');

//ReportController
public function index($start_time = null, $end_time = null) {
    // $start_time = null;
}

public function index($start_time = null, $end_time = null, User $user = null) {
    // $start_time = [];
}
```

Comment: Show situation where you call these methods

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: You’d be better off just using query string parameters (accessible via `$request->query('key')`).